# Python organizing text file to excel (absolute rookie)

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, openpyxl

Ok, so here is the thing..

I am completely new to python and I'm trying to write a script that converts a text file to excel.
The idea is that the text file will be configuration output from several network devices.

for example a network switch will vill look like this:

---

interface 1
name "firewall"
tagged vlan 2-20

interface 2
name "computer"
untagged vlan 10

interface 3
name "access point"
untagged vlan 10
tagged vlan 3-7

interface 4
untagged vlan 15

interface 5
name "uplink"
untagged vlan 9
tagged vlan 5

and so on...

---

As you see, every interface have individual configuration so I cannot simply copy the line numbers that I want, since the amount of lines for each interface is pretty dynamic for each switch.

I am trying to put this into excel with row A being interface numbers, row B Untagged Vlan if applicable, row C tagged Vlan if applicable and row D name if applicable

I have been trying to learn by using a combination of just manipulating in the text editor and then importing to openpyxl, I have tried converting to csv and then manipulating, and I have tried actually importing to xlsx straight away and then manipulating, but every single time it actually falls apart as soon as I get past interface 1.

I have been trying to watch what I can on Youtube as well with little luck, does anyone have any ideas as to what commands I can use to actually group the different interfaces together so that when I import them to excel they have a set pattern that I can use to actually move the different values around with?

sorry for very "general" question, I do not intend for anyone to write out the entire code for me, I am simply trying to learn what commands might be useful in this case.

Comment: Can you add a clear expected output based on the `.txt` you shared ?

Comment: Also do you have possibility to change text file? I think a `delimiter` would be very helpful here. `interface 1; name "firewall"; untagged vlan X; tagged vlan Y` would make this way clear and stable.

Comment: [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/QY6GShN/)

Thank you so much both of you! 

I have tried to make an example of what I want in this comment.

Comment: Can you share raw sample of your file as text instead of image? People must be able to copy paste for recreating your problem. Also make sure it is accurate as in your excel example your lines contain different data as in your example here.

Comment: Hello again, 

Of course, that is no problem. 
I have actually taken the entire config from the switch as I get it and just removed sensitive information. please note that this is for all 8 interfaces, not only for 5 interfaces as in the example I postet originally. (the same logic applies) 
[github](https://github.com/Invisasura/Openpyxl_example/blob/main/README.md/)